# Changing git user on local branch before pushing to remote

Tags: git, git-push

I am in the following situation:

I was given a development machine, with all the repos tied to somebody else's git credentials. I created a new local branch, made a bunch of commits, across 9 or 10 repos. I now have an account on the company's git server and I want to push my local branch to the remote server (same branch, don't need to change anything there).

However, I need it to show all the commits as being made by me, not by the other person who was using this laptop before me.

Is there a way to do this? Do I need to somehow go back and change the user associated with all these local commits to myself and, if so, how can I do that? Open to hacks if necessary.

Comment: As always with `git`, you'll need to go back and redo all of the commits to change something about them, even just the author. As long as the commits haven't been pushed elsewhere yet (which seems like the case here), this is fine, and the script below looks good. Just as a warning to people coming to this later, though, who might not realize the context when Google lands them here - don't change history (commits) you've already shared with others!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout GitHub's [script](https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-author-info) for "changing author info":

> To change the name and/or email address recorded in existing commits,
>   you must rewrite the entire history of your Git repository.
>
> **Warning: This action is destructive to your repository's history. If
>   you're collaborating on a repository with others, it's considered bad
>   practice to rewrite published history. You should only do this in an
>   emergency.**
>
> ### Changing the Git history of your repository using a script
>
> We've
>   created a script that will change any commits that previously had the
>   old email address in its author or committer fields to use the correct
>   name and email address.
>
> *Note: Running this script rewrites history for all repository
>   collaborators. After completing these steps, any person with forks or
>   clones must fetch the rewritten history and rebase any local changes
>   into the rewritten history.*
>
> Before running this script, you'll need:
>
> - The old email address that appears in the author/committer fields that
>     you want to change
> - The correct name and email address that you would
>     like such commits to be attributed to
>
> Instructions:
>
> 1. Open Terminal.
> 2. Create a fresh, bare clone of your repository:
>
> ```
> git clone --bare https://github.com/user/repo.git`
> cd repo.git
> ```
>
> 3. Copy and paste the script, replacing the following variables based on
>      the information you gathered:
>
> ```
> OLD_EMAIL
> CORRECT_NAME
> CORRECT_EMAIL
> #!/bin/sh
>
> git filter-branch --env-filter '
>
> OLD_EMAIL="your-old-email@example.com"
> CORRECT_NAME="Your Correct Name"
> CORRECT_EMAIL="your-correct-email@example.com"
>
> if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
> then
>     export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
>     export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
> fi
> if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
> then
>     export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
>     export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
> fi
> ' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
> ```
>
> 4. Press **Enter** to run the script.
> 5. Review the new Git history for errors.
> 6. Push the corrected history to GitHub:
>
>    git push --force --tags origin 'refs/heads/*'
> 7. Clean up the temporary clone:
>
> ```
> cd ..
> rm -rf repo.git
> ```

Comment: Note that this will change the author of *all* the commits made by the original author, not just those you made after you inherited the laptop. If the original author has made any commits in the repository, and you rewrite **all** of the history, and you're on a team, I can almost guarantee you that nobody will be too happy with you for doing this. **Make sure you only change the commits you made**

Comment: As with all git commands that rewrite history, **make sure you understand what it does**, this includes force-pushing. To be honest, I think you should go and talk to the team lead or your software architect about this issue before you start force-pushing to a central repository. "They said to do so on Stack Overflow" doesn't sit well if everybody now have stale branches in the repository and you generate a ton of work to make sure everybody can continue working.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Good call, and thanks for the heads up; I won't go into it blindly. I'll see if there's a way to limit the author re-writes to a single branch / past a certain date first before I decide to press the big red button.